# Planarity Checking for Building walls

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, 3d-model

While viewing 3D buildings in ArcScene, a flickering error(refer screenshot below) can be seen visually due to the Non planar surface. The options I have checked are Topology in ArcGIS & QGIS, Geometry checker in QGIS, but it does not find the errors.

[image: Circled in red are the errors of Non Planar surface in Building walls]

It would be better if someone provides solution to find the error in any free softwares/Tools

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to choose one software solution. Questions seeking multiple sofware solutions are effectively multiple questions, which violates the "One question per Question" policy.

Comment: Edited the question!